# Inserting PNG images inside a box created with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created website which code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/7y373j8x/2

I have created a box which appears when clicking on "Portfolio". (The box is called "`object2`").

I want to insert `PNG` images inside of this box. Some have suggested to me to do a `jQuery slider` but I don't want a `slideshow`. I want the images to be placed next to each other (as `thumbnails`) and then the user can click on an image and it should become bigger.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="map" src="http://www.local-guru.net/img/guru/worldglow.png" alt="map" />


<div class="container">
    <p>About me</p>
    <div id="portfolio" onclick="show();">Portfolio</div>
    <p>Contact me</p>
    <div id="object2" onclick="show();">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#map {
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container {
    color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 54%;
    left: 58px;
    font-family: normal normal 15px Calibri;
}

#object2 {
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 200px;
    right: 400px;
    width: 650px;
    height: 350px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function show() {
    document.getElementById("object2").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Check console log in jsfiddle.

Comment: In jsfiddle, you are loading an external file with http. Only https file can be added in jsfiddle external file option

Comment: In your jsfiddle code, when you click on "portfolio", its not able to find the show() function. Hence issue is seen.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/saTfR/56/

Comment: you guys are all jumping to conclusions.  If you remove the image, it still doesn't work. here I've removed all the css and image and the function is still not defined. http://jsfiddle.net/7y373j8x/

Comment: @Sushil can you check this fiddle, now I'm really confused why it's not working http://jsfiddle.net/7y373j8x/

Comment: instead of using `onload` try using `no wrap in <head>` in jsfiddle. here's ur updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7y373j8x/1/

Comment: I have updated the link

Comment: how do you want to insert images in this box?

Comment: @Sushil Whichever is the best/easiest way. I am a beginner in web development so I am not sure which is the best way.

Comment: ok. so where are these images going to come from? did you have a look at my first fiddle? does that work for you?

Comment: @Sushil the images are in the same folder as my HTML, CSS, etc. I looked at your fiddle and I put the code under the javascript script in the HTML file. My images (ex. 'image.png') do not show up inside the box. I even used your image links and it does not show up. So I am trying to figure why

Comment: what you can try is first try to load the images in an image tag normally to see if they're even showing up on your page in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85154/discussion-between-sushil-and-toronto23).

Comment: can you also share your updated html that is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append the images using `javascript` or `jquery`.

update your `show()` method like this.

```
function show(){        
    document.getElementById("object2").style.display = "block";
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'https://placehold.it/350x150';
    var image1 = new Image();
    image1.src = 'https://placehold.it/200x100';
    $('#object2').html('');
    $('#object2').append(image);
    $('#object2').append(image1);
}
```

here's the updated **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/saTfR/61/)** for the same. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your function is not working is because `onclick` operates within the page scope so it can't execute any functions outside of it.

If I moved the script within the same scope, it will work as you can see here:

**JavaScript jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/saTfR/60/

( I have replaced your `style.display = "block"` with `.style.cssText = 'display: block';` )

---

**jQuery Approach**

If you are interested in using jQuery, here is a cleaner and easier jQuery approach to modifying css properties with js:

```
$("#portfolio").click(function(){
    $("#object2").css("display", "block");
});
```

**jQuery jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/saTfR/58/